# Weird issue with orchestration and send port filters

Tags: biztalk

I've got a weird issue which totally confused me. I have an orchestration that receives a file through Receive port and puts it to Send port with delivery notification. After that orchestration performs some other actions but my issue is with the part mentioned above. It works: I put a file to Receive location and it goes to appropriate destination folder.

But, if I assign to the Send port a filter that uses fields promoted in message and filter's expression is False it still works - I receive file in destination folder (however filter is False and Send port should not process this file). And once filter becomes True I receive...THREE equal files in destination folder!

Are there any logs that I can go through to try to figure out where these two extra files come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when you add a filter to a send port, if the Orchestration is bound to the send port, it will still send through that send port, regardless what other filters you put on it.

In the Admin Console you do a query for Subscriptions and find the send port, you will notice that it will have an OR condition with `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties.SPTransportID == {GUID}`  and that is the filter that is used when a an Orchestration sends to a bound send port.

So check what the filter looks like for your send port.   Also check to see if you have a send port group set up that includes that send port, as that would also cause a message to be sent to that send port if the filter on that matches.

What is probably happening is that the Orchestration is sending one, and the filter is matching the message received from the Receive Location.  You will have to do some more digging to see why the third message.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for perfect explanation. Now I understand that if I want to use additional filters I should use Filter expression in Receive shape in orchestration. But is it possible to allow to configure this filter expression when I configure already built and deployed orchestration in BizTalk Admin, not when I design it in VisualStudio?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to do it in Visual Studio, you can't change filters for Orchestrations via the Admin console

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.